# Hibernate query cache doesn't work when criteria implies date

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-cache

I have the following query:

```
public List<SomeEntity> findArticlesById(String id) {
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<SomeEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(SomeEntity.class);
    final Root<SomeEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(SomeEntity.class);
    final Join<SomeEntity, SomeOtherEntity> join = root.join(SomeEntity.property);

    criteriaQuery
            .select(root)
            .where(
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(SomeEntity_.id), id),
                    criteriaBuilder.between(criteriaBuilder.literal(new Date()), join.get(SomeEntity_.startDate), join.get(SomeEntity_.endDate))
            );

    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_REGION, CacheRegions.QUERY_ENTITY)
            .getResultList();
}
```

I'd expect the query cache to be hit when I call twice, however it doesn't work.

However, if I remove 2nd predicate

```
criteriaBuilder.between(criteriaBuilder.literal(new Date()), join.get(SomeEntity_.startDate), join.get(SomeEntity_.endDate)
```

cache work properly instead.

What is the cause ?

**EDIT**

class definition:

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_ENTITY")
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SomeEntityPk pk;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SomeOtherEntity someOtherEntity;

    ...

@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_ENTITY")
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SomeEntityPk pk;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SomeOtherEntity someOtherEntity;

    ...

@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
@Table(name="SOME_OTHER_ENTITY")
public class SomeOtherEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="DATE_START")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="DATE_END")
    private Date endDate;
    
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy=SomeEntity_.SOMEOTHERENTITY)
    private List<SomeEntity> someEntities;
    
    ...
```

I'm using Hibernate 5.3.12.Final

Comment: Could you please show the `SomeEntity` entity, hibernate config. What hibernate version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't think you are reusing the query that is cached because you are using `new Date()` in the criteria builder and as a result `parameter`s bound to the query is different every time.

```
   criteriaBuilder.between(criteriaBuilder.literal(new Date())...
```

- For testing purpose, modify `findArticlesById` method to  `findArticlesById(String id, Date date)` and pass the same `date` to both calls and see